# relation between two form fields

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm new in django. I need somthing like this in my form.py:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES1 = (('a','a'),
               ('b','b'),)
    field1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES1)
#if field1=='a':
    CHOICES2 = (('c','c'),
               ('d','d'),)
    field2 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES2) 
#if field1=='b':
    CHOICES2 = (('e','e'),
               ('f','f'),)
    field2 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES2)
```

but I have no idea how should I do this.

Comment: When do you want to choose the value of `field2`? Dynamically on the webpage? This will require Javascript. While saving something to the database? Then you should use a model. For any other cases you can use the [form and field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/validation/)

Comment: yes I want to use it Dynamically on the webpage. can you give me a simple example ?

Comment: I had to cope with this problem myself. I solved it by setting `required=False` in each optional form field and by doing the validation and display of the respective choices on the client side using JavaScript and jQuery. See [here](http://jquery.com/) and [here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). In any case, you have to make use of JavaScript. You cannot accomplish your goal with Python and Django alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no simple way to do this. You'll need Javascript and custom validation on the server.

Using jQuery, the client code might look like this:

```
var F2_CHOICES = {
    'a' : { 'c' : 'c', 'd' : 'd'},
    'b' : { 'e' : 'e', 'f' : 'f'}
};
var $field2 = $('[name=field2]');
  $('[name=field1]').change(
  function() {
      var currentValue = $(this).val() ;
      $field2.empty();
      for (o in F2_CHOICES[currentValue]){
            $field2.append('<option '+' value="'+o+'">'+F2_CHOICES[currentValue][o]+'</option>');
      }
  });
```

On the server, you'll need to define a `clean` method on your form to check if field2 value is one of the choices that correspond to field1 value.